# What are the divisions in CoD Ghosts clan wars?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

Is it like the following descending order:

1. Platinum
2. Gold
3. Silver
4. Bronze

or is it like last call of duty where Master is the highest division.

Comment: If you're going to down-vote a question, at least comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently just those four divisions, in the order you specified.

Comment: ps wasn't a yes/no question

Comment: Then you shouldn't have marked it as the answer.

Comment: @editor: the nope is fine because of the last line of the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are five divisions in Call of Duty Ghosts.  This will be ordered from top to bottem of rank of the divisions.

1. Diamond division
2. Platinum
3. Gold
4. Silver
5. Bronze

> These are the five divisions in Call of Duty Ghosts following the patch in early Febrary after the DLC was released. A few days after the DLC Infinity Ward announced a new Division which is Diamond division. Check the Call of Duty app or website for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 4 listed, there is also Diamond Division.
This division is intended for the tournament qualification.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  If you wish to help the poster, please add some more information about the Diamond Division.  Perhaps where it fits in, what you have to do to attain it, etc.  If there was a source that you are quoting, perhaps you can also include a link.